# Updating window indexes with tmux?

Tags: tmux

Using tmux, I closed a window indexed 3, so now I have 1,2,4, ...

I'd rather have windows sequential, so is there any way to force them to re-index?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

*tmux* 1.7 includes the `renumber-windows` session option that maintains a “gapless” sequence for a session’s window numbers. You can set the option “globally” to have it apply to all sessions that have not overridden the global value. E.g. in your `~/.tmux.conf`:

```
set-option -g renumber-windows on
```

If you do not always want all your sessions to have “gapless” window numbers, then you can use `move-window -r` (the option is also new to *tmux 1.7) to renumber the windows in just the current session (or some other session if you use the `-t` option).

Comment: thanks for this option, that's exactly what I was looking for. tmux is amazing

Comment: It's worth to mention that the re-indexing currently happens on any window move "event". So, a window move may be required with a reloaded config while Tmux is running.

Answer (score 3):

There's no builtin way to do it, but this bash script should work. Run it from within the session:

```
i=0
tmux list-windows | cut -d: -f1 | while read winindex; do 
  if (( winindex != i )); then
    tmux move-window -d -s $winindex -t $i
  fi
  (( i++ ))
done
```

The `-d` flag to `move-window` avoids giving that window focus.

Comment: That worked, thanks. I had a zero window actually, so I needed to start with i=0.

Comment: Ah I forgot I had `set-option -g base-index 1` in `.tmux.conf`.

Comment: Even with the tmux 1.7 new features, I found this implementation useful to avoid moving some windows.

Comment: And if you have multiple sessions, this script does similar: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8835493/686629